# Why does it return true when I insert any different string than " "

Tags: java, equals

This is my first question here so I'm sorry for any mistake. I am writing a tic-tac-toe game. I have problem with this.

```
if (!table[0][0].equals(" ") && !table[1][0].equals(" ") && !table[2][0].equals(" ") &&
    !table[0][1].equals(" ") && !table[1][1].equals(" ") && !table[2][1].equals(" ") &&
    !table[0][2].equals(" ") && !table[1][2].equals(" ") && !table[2][2].equals(" ")) {
    System.out.println("Draw!");
    return true;
}
```

For example: if I insert any `String` in `table[0][0]`, it returns `true` despite other fields being `" "`.

Comment: try initializing all elements in the grid to a value like "_", it may be a problem between confusing an empty field and a space value...

Comment: as you have added && operation so you must be true all the conditions

Comment: I ran this according to your scenario and it returns `false`. The problem might not be in this block.

Comment: How have you initialized table[][] please paste that part?

Comment: [It shouldn't return true. The problem is somewhere else.](http://ideone.com/bLTo4q)

Answer (score 0):

I have initialized table in Board class. This is the constructor:

```
public Board() {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    board = new Mark[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j] = new Mark(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my checkResult method:

```
        public boolean checkResult() {
    if ((table[0][0] == table[1][0] && table[1][0] == table[2][0] && !table[2][0].equals(" "))
            || (table[0][1] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][1] && !table[2][1].equals(" "))
            || (table[0][2] == table[1][2] && table[1][2] == table[2][2] && !table[2][2].equals(" "))
            || (table[0][0] == table[0][1] && table[0][1] == table[0][2] && !table[0][2].equals(" "))
            || (table[1][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[1][2] && !table[1][2].equals(" "))
            || (table[2][0] == table[2][1] && table[2][1] == table[2][2] && !table[2][2].equals(" "))
            || (table[0][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][2] && !table[2][2].equals(" "))
            || (table[0][2] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][0] && !table[2][0].equals(" "))) {
        System.out.println("You won");

        return true;
    }
    if (!table[0][0].equals(" ") && !table[1][0].equals(" ") && !table[2][0].equals(" ") && !table[0][1].equals(" ")
            && !table[1][1].equals(" ") && !table[2][1].equals(" ") && !table[0][2].equals(" ")
            && !table[1][2].equals(" ") && !table[2][2].equals(" ")) {
        System.out.println("Draw!");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And this is my Test class:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logika lg = new Logika();

    do{
    lg.insertMark2();
    lg.printBoard();

    } while(!(lg.checkResult()));

}
```

}

When I do my first insert, program stops.